# how to check postgresql session count?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to monitor PostgreSQL.

When I want to query the number of sessions，I found an SQL:

```
select count(*) as session_count 
from (
   select sess_id 
   from pg_stat_activity 
   group by sess_id
) as activity;
```

But `sess_id` does not exist in the latest version.

Is `sess_id` replaced by another field? Can I check the number of sessions in another way?

Comment: SQL-only questions are generally better asked on the dba.stackexchange.com sister site, especially with regard to monitoring the database system.

Answer (score 3):

The total count of open connections is as simple as

```
select count(*) 
from pg_stat_activity
```

no `group by` necessary.

There has never been a `sess_id` column in [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)

Comment: What is the difference between session and connection?Should the number of query be less than session?

Comment: @trgbishi: that's the same

Comment: I found another way to get connections for database."select datname,numbackends from pg_stat_database;“Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the query

select * from pg_stat_activity;

this query will give you the complete information
and if you just want count then you can use

select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;